# Присоединение файлов в почте в Perl

Tags: email, perl

Здравствуйте. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как присоединять в Perl файлы , например, графические, к электронным письмам.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [MIME::Lite](http://www.akadia.com/services/email_attachments_using_perl.html#Email%20attachments%20using%20Perl%20/%20MIME::Lite):

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

### Выбрать отправителя получателя и почтовика
my $from_address = 'sample@yandex.ru';
my $to_address = 'sample@yandex.ru';
my $mail_host = 'smtp.yandex.ru';

### Выбрать тело и заголовок сообщения
my $subject = 'Пример письма с вложением';
my $message_body = "Тело письма с вложением";

### Выбрать имена файлов
my $my_file_gif = 'my_file.gif';
my $your_file_gif = 'your_file.gif';

### Создать контейнер
$msg = MIME::Lite->new (
  From => $from_address,
  To => $to_address,
  Subject => $subject,
  Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Ошибка создания контейнера: $!\n";

### Добавить текст
$msg->attach (
  Type => 'TEXT',
  Data => $message_body
) or die "Ошибка добавления текста: $!\n";

### Добавить рисунок
$msg->attach (
   Type => 'image/gif',
   Path => $my_file_gif,
   Filename => $your_file_gif,
   Disposition => 'attachment'
) or die "Ошибка добавления $file_gif: $!\n";

### Послать сообщение
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $mail_host, Timeout=>60);
$msg->send;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Отправка писем с вложениями на Perl](http://semenushkin.ru/2011/07/12/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-perl/).